How can I deploy to an Azure Function app deployment slot?
I have created a function app deployment slot. I have published from Visual Studio and it says your Function app is ready.
But when I go to the Function app slot I cant see any functions, it says
  We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. Refresh the page to 
 try again
  Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.

and on the top of the page it says :
  microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask: Task Hub name must be specified in 
  host.json when using slots. Specified name must not equal the default HubName 
  (funcapp1).

Is the host.json in my app or do I need to do it on Azure ?
Also can i give it any name or do I need to create a Hub ?
And when i deploy to a slot is it the same as to a function app direct as follows:
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "MyResourceGroup" -n
"appslotname"  --src $sourceZipPath   ?

just want to confirm, are able to select deployment slots during deployment, and after deployment to specific slots you are function is not visible in function

Can you share your code?

There are no functions .. it gives the error as above

Is there any setting i need to put or change , has anyone encounted this with function app slots ?  The function app works fine but the slot doesnt

How can i check  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version ?

To deploy function to Deployment slots from Visual Studio select deployment slots from the list to which slot you want to deploy.

Note : Production slot will not be available in the list as It is default slot, if you do not select any slot from list.



I deployed  a sample Http Trigger function.
Function.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;

        public Function(ILogger<Function> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}


How can i check Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version ?

You can define version in .csproj file. My function version is 4
and dotnet version is 8

Note : In-process model uses Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.extension package and Isolated Process uses Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker package.


Make sure you are using correct packages in correct Process model.

FunctionApp4.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

OUTPUT:




for my solution some project that are shared in the project  have netstandard2.0 while the project i deploy has net48 ?

even if i create a new slot it gives the error :   We were not able to load some functions in the list due to errors. Refresh the page to try again, error: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.

@Melissa your .net veraion is very old version.  AFAIK, current ly you can .net function with lowest .net veraion is 6

Check the function app is using which .net version. In configuration settings of function app in portal
